# Ubuntu Hangs While Working

Tags: wubi

I have installed ubuntu 10.04 via wubi. Frequently ubuntu hangs while working. Even installer hanged when I tried to install ubuntu recent version, linux mint 10 via wubi & mint4win. Is this problem related to hardware? My configuraion is

- Intel dual core 3. GHz
- Intel motherboard
- 160GB HDD
- 2 GB DDR2 RAM

I'm using onboard graphics Intel 82945G Express chipset. No external graphic card.

Comment: What graphics card are you using?

Comment: Please add some hardware information to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is a common problem with Open Source drivers and kernel mode setting. You can disable it using:

`sudo echo options i915 modeset=0 > /etc/modprobe.d/i915-kms.conf`

Source: http://calebflynn.com/node/4