# Ubuntu Hangs While Working

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu Hangs While Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35417/ubuntu-hangs-while-working)

I have installed ubuntu lucid in my machine with windows.Ubuntu hangs even when there is no activity.I could not start any application.It hangs only in gui mode.Do you need more information?Any help would be appreciated?

Intel dual core 3.GHZ Intel motherboard 160GB HDD 2 GB DDR2 RAM

I m using onboard graphics Intel 82945G Express chipset.No external graphic card

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly do you mean by "hangs"?