# Resolution goes to 640x480 after disabling KMS

Tags: nvidia, display, resolution, asus, kms

This Ubuntu 12.04 box happens to freeze all of a sudden under regular usage - anything seems to be able to make it freeze. In one effort of seeing what could fix it, I've disabled KMS (Kernel ModeSetting), as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/59512/61520).

In my case, it is:

```
echo options nouveau modeset=0 > /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf
```

Since this is an NVIDIA GeForce2 Integrated (on-board) card on an old motherboard (A7N266-VM).

And after it restarts, the only resolution avaliable is 640x480, while before, it could do 1024x768.

I want to know if disabling KMS fixes my problem, so:

**How can I have the correct (1024x768) resolution with KMS disabled?**

Answer (score 0):

I've come with an answer this time. But I've also got a question in case somebody wants to help me out too.

Okay, so here's the answer for my problem, I don't know if this will work for you, but you can (and probably have already) try. Reboot and go into recovery mode. Choose to run failsafe graphics mode. Choose what I believe is the second option, it's something like "restore default graphics". Do this and then reboot.

To answer your question (in a previous comment), it happened all of a sudden. I've got it mostly fixed now. Ubuntu is back to normal resolution, but once I log in as user, it still registers that my settings want 640x480 and the resolution changes. But I can't go into Displays and change my settings, because the save button is cut off at the bottom of the screen and I can't press it. The window size seems impossible to change. Got any ideas of how to fix that?

Edit: I fixed this (accidentally) by pressing Fn+F8, which is the command to change displays on my machine.

Comment: My best guess is that you should look at editing xorg.conf through the console, which probably doesn't exist so you'd have to `X -configure` or something. But in any case, you'd be better off asking it as a separate question, not because I'm bothered, but because it has higher chances of people seeing it and responding. In my case, I can have the correct resolution by not disabling KMS. By the way, try re-installing Ubuntu. If your `/home` partition is separate from your `/` partition (it should, it's easy to do), it will be easy to re-install, and all your settings will be there, everything.

Comment: See my newest edit for how I ended up fixing this. I don't really understand how that helped, but it was nicer than reinstalling. Thanks though, Camilo, for your input!

Comment: I'm glad you solved it :)